# Save multiple files with multiple names with R

Tags: r

I have three files (T1.dnd, T2.dnd, T3.dnd) in which in all of them i have to substitude a specific row with another one with mgsub function. After doing that i have to save these files separately in a new folder (Output) with their respective names (T1.dnd, T2.dnd, T3.dnd) with a for loop. However the loop save only the last file (T3.dnd) and not all three (so T1.dnd and T2.dnd are missing).

How can i save all the three files with their names?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

```
library(mgsub)

setwd("C:/Users/feder/Project/test")
treat <- as.list(c("C:/Users/feder/Project/test/T1.dnd",
                   "C:/Users/feder/Project/test/T2.dnd",
                   "C:/Users/feder/Project/test/T3.dnd"))
step <- list()
step2 <- list()

step <- lapply(treat, readLines)
step2 <- lapply(step, mgsub, c("______Leaf_fraction__________0.3100"),
                             c("______Leaf_fraction__________0.1500"))

files <- list.files("C:/Users/feder/Project/test")
names_files <- as.list(files)

savewd <- c("C:/Users/feder/Project/Output")


for (i in length(step2)){
  writeLines(step2[[i]], paste(savewd, names_files[[i]], sep = "/"))
}
```

Comment: `for (i in length(step2))` -> `for (i in 1:length(step2))`.

Comment: Might be preferable to use `for (i in seq_along(step2))`. It is more robust if you in the future have zero files that need to be changed.